# an effective way to convert from a number to its position on a matrix

Tags: c

I want to make an input system that will allow the user to choose a number and it will return the position of choice.
for example:

```
     | 0  1  2
   --+----------
   0 | 1  2  3
   1 | 4  5  6
   2 | 7  8  9
```

in this matrix, if the user input is 5 it should return the position {1, 1} and if the input is 8 it should return {2, 1}.

I wrote a piece of code to try and do that but it doesn't work well for every scenario:

here is the code I wrote in **C language**:

```
VectorPos RequestInput(char arr[][3])
{
    char input;
    int converted;
    VectorPos loc;

    while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter number between 1-9: ");
        scanf(" %c", &input);
        if (input < '1' || input > '9')
            printf("Invalid board Location.\n\n");
        else
            break;
    }
    converted = atoi(&input);
    int count = 1;
    int i, k;
    i = k = 0;
    for (k = 0; k < 3 && count++ < converted; k++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 3 && count++ < converted; i++);
    }
    loc.col = k;
    loc.row = i;
    return loc;
}
```

*VectorPos is just a struct to return a row and col in one variable.

I would like to ask if you know of any good more effective way of doing this.
thanks:)

Comment: You should read much more about [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques (e.g. first chapters of the [Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools)...) and consider using [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch ... I don't see how parsing and Bison relates to this question at all?

Comment: @AKX: the first sentence of the question mention *input system*. I am not a native English speaker, but for me any kind of input is related to parsing

Comment: @Michael: please provide some [mre] in your question - we need the declaration of `VectorPos`. Take inspiration from open source software, e.g. on [github](https://github.com/), similar to your needs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a rectangular grid like that, all you need is division and modulo:

```
// pos = position in grid from 1..
// w = grid width
// x = output x variable (range 0..w-1)
// y = output y variable (range 0..infinity)
// usage: pos_to_xy(4, 3, &x, &y);
void pos_to_xy(int pos, int w, int *x, int *y) {
  pos -= 1;  // Bring range 1.. to 0..
  *y = pos / w;
  *x = pos % w;
}
```

Example:

```
int main() {
    for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        int x, y;
        pos_to_xy(i, 3, &x, &y);
        printf("%d: (x %d, y %d)\n", i, x, y);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1: (x 0, y 0)
2: (x 1, y 0)
3: (x 2, y 0)
4: (x 0, y 1)
5: (x 1, y 1)
6: (x 2, y 1)
7: (x 0, y 2)
8: (x 1, y 2)
9: (x 2, y 2)
```